# My Ajax form is returning null to my controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm doing post processing with Ajax BeginForm. The value coming to the controller is null.But when I use the `SettingViewModel` instead, null does not appear. But I need to use my `UsersRegister` model.

Razor :

```
@model GAP_Bakim.ViewModel.SettingViewModel

 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Details", "Setting", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "detailSuccess", OnFailure = "detailFailure" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="input-box mb-3">
                        <span>Kullanıcı Adı</span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UsersDetails.username, new { @class = "form-control details-inputs", id = "detailUsernameInput", required = "required", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-box mb-3">
                        <span>Ad</span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UsersDetails.kullaniciAd, new { @class = "form-control details-inputs", id = "detailNameInput", required = "required", maxlength = 25, pattern = "[A-Za-zğüşıöçĞÜŞİÖÇ\u0020]+" })
                    </div>
```

Controller :

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Details(UsersDetails users)
```

ViewModel :

```
 public class SettingViewModel
    {
        public Settings Settings { get; set; }
        public UsersDetails UsersDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

Model :

```
 public class UsersDetails
    {
        public string username { get; set; }

        public string kullaniciAd { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`TextBoxFor` is automatically generating a `name` attribute based on the model property:

```
m.UsersDetails.username
```

And that attribute is what provides the key in the key/value pairs sent to the server.  Unless otherwise indicated, the framework assumes the same model will be used in the subsequent action, which isn't the case here.  So the resulting name attribute:

```
name="UsersDetails.username"
```

Doesn't match the property name on your model:

```
public string username { get; set; }
```

You can manually override the `name` attribute in the HTML attributes for `TextBoxFor`:

```
new { name = "username", @class = "form-control details-inputs", id = "detailUsernameInput", required = "required", @readonly = "readonly" }
      ^-- here
```

Do the same for the other `TextBoxFor` so its resulting `name` attribute matches its intended model property as well.